# How to inspect which pod networking add-on is used in my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

There are many for [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) in Kubernetes.

How can I inspect with `kubeadm` or `kubectl` which networking (flannel, calico, ..) gets used in my cluster?

Background: I play with K8s on some virtual machines.

Answer (score 3):

`ls /etc/cni/net.d` shows the CNI plugins you have installed and configured.

Answer (score 2):

CNI configuration is found under `/etc/cni/net.d`. But there can be many plugin configurations found under `/etc/cni/net.d`, so it depends on the weightage of the file. The plugin-file with highest weightage(in name) is applied.

Example: in this case file 20-* will be chosen.

```
10-weave.conflist
20-weave.conflist
```

The name and type filed of the plugin configuration file specifies which plugin to be applied from the `/opt/cni/bin/` folder.

```
sudo cat /etc/cni/net.d/20-weave.conflist
{
    "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
    "name": "weave",
    "plugins": [
        {
            "name": "weave",
            "type": "weave-net",
            "hairpinMode": true
        },
        {
            "type": "portmap",
            "capabilities": {"portMappings": true},
            "snat": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Verify the created pods using this command:
`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

```
weave-net-cc6np                    2/2     Running   6 (30m ago)   17d
weave-net-mkvzd                    2/2     Running   5 (33m ago)   17d
```